# Why does scan for large blob value crash HBase cluster?

Tags: java, hbase, cloudera-cdh, database-scan

I have an HBase table in which I have two column families, 'i:*' for info, and 'f:b' for file:blob.
I am storing images in the value, some images are almost 12MB.

I can load/insert the files no problem in java, but as soon as I try to retrieve them via a scan for the f:b family value (the blobs), my scanner sits until it times out and every region server on my cluster dies in sequence (I have a 20 node cluster). The only way to stop this quasi virus that my scanner somehow inflicts upon my helpless nodes is to drop the table altogether (or so it seems).

I am using Cloudera EDH '0.98.6-cdh5.2.0'

unfortunately my client just times out, so no valuable exceptions there, and all I could get from my node logs are below

```
2014-10-27 21:47:36,106 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver: Failed to archive class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver$FileablePath, file:hdfs://nameservice1/hbase/data/default/RASTER/92ceb2d86662ad6d959f4cc384229e0f/recovered.edits/0000000000000000029.temp
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs://nameservice1/hbase/data/default/RASTER/92ceb2d86662ad6d959f4cc384229e0f/recovered.edits/0000000000000000029.temp does not exist.
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatusInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:658)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$600(DistributedFileSystem.java:104)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$14.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:716)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$14.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:712)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:712)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver$FileablePath.getChildren(HFileArchiver.java:628)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver.resolveAndArchive(HFileArchiver.java:346)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver.resolveAndArchive(HFileArchiver.java:347)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver.resolveAndArchive(HFileArchiver.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver.archiveRegion(HFileArchiver.java:137)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver.archiveRegion(HFileArchiver.java:75)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.cleanParent(CatalogJanitor.java:333)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.scan(CatalogJanitor.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.chore(CatalogJanitor.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Chore.run(Chore.java:87)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2014-10-27 21:47:36,129 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver: Failed to complete archive of: [class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver$FileablePath, file:hdfs://nameservice1/hbase/data/default/RASTER/92ceb2d86662ad6d959f4cc384229e0f/recovered.edits/0000000000000000029.temp]. Those files are still in the original location, and they may slow down reads.
2014-10-27 21:47:36,129 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor: Failed scan of catalog table
java.io.IOException: Received error when attempting to archive files ([class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver$FileablePath, file:hdfs://nameservice1/hbase/data/default/RASTER/92ceb2d86662ad6d959f4cc384229e0f/f, class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver$FileablePath, file:hdfs://nameservice1/hbase/data/default/RASTER/92ceb2d86662ad6d959f4cc384229e0f/i, class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver$FileablePath, file:hdfs://nameservice1/hbase/data/default/RASTER/92ceb2d86662ad6d959f4cc384229e0f/recovered.edits]), cannot delete region directory. 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver.archiveRegion(HFileArchiver.java:148)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.backup.HFileArchiver.archiveRegion(HFileArchiver.java:75)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.cleanParent(CatalogJanitor.java:333)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.scan(CatalogJanitor.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.chore(CatalogJanitor.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Chore.run(Chore.java:87)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2014-10-27 21:47:36,146 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.SplitLogManager: Done splitting /hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Finsight-staging-slave019.spadac.com%2C60020%2C1414446135179-splitting%2Finsight-staging-slave019.spadac.com%252C60020%252C1414446135179.1414446317771
```

here is my code for scanning the table

```
    try {
      if (hBaseConfig == null) {
        hBaseConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        hBaseConfig.setInt("hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period", 1200000);
        hBaseConfig.set("hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize", "0");
        hBaseConfig.set("hbase.master", PROPS.get().getProperty("hbase.master"));
        hBaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", PROPS.get().getProperty("zks"));
        hBaseConfig.set("zks.port", "2181");
        table = new HTable(hBaseConfig, "RASTER");
      }

      Scan scan = new Scan();
      scan.addColumn("f".getBytes(), "b".getBytes());
      scan.addColumn("i".getBytes(), "name".getBytes());
      ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);

      for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr = scanner.next()) {
/*I NEVER EVEN GET HERE IF I SCAN FOR 'f:b'*/
        CellScanner cs = rr.cellScanner();
        String name = "";
        byte[] fileBs = null;
        while (cs.advance()) {

          Cell current = cs.current();

          byte[] cloneValue = CellUtil.cloneValue(current);
          byte[] cloneFamily = CellUtil.cloneFamily(current);
          byte[] qualBytes = CellUtil.cloneQualifier(current);
          String fam = Bytes.toString(cloneFamily);
          String qual = Bytes.toString(qualBytes);
          if (fam.equals("i")) {

            if (qual.equals("name")) {
              name = Bytes.toString(cloneValue);
            }
          } else if (fam.equals("f") && qual.equals("b")) {
            fileBs = cloneValue;
          }

        }

        OutputStream bof = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\" + name);
        bof.write(fileBs);
        break;

      }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      //removed
    }
```

thanks
Does anyone know why a scan for a large blob might annihilate my cluster? I am sure it's silly just can't figure it out.

Comment: BTW, I can scan on other columns no problem with the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was the problem

```
hBaseConfig.set("hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize", "0");
```

I changed it to "50" and it works now.